# nondeterministic finite automation question

Tags: finite-automata, non-deterministic

Im doing some studying and im a bit confused on this little nondeterministic algorithm when it processes a 1. I understand that it will split into a brand with q1 since a 0 or 1 will redirect back, and that theres an exit arrow to q2 is there is a 1, but why would it split into q3? I feel like im misreading the (0,empty string), any clarification would be great.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty string means that you can take it at *any* time. In this case, a 1 will take it to q2 and because q2 has an empty string arrow to q3. It will also immediately take that without having to get the next bit of the input.

Comment: ah okay. If thats the case, why would the branch the 4th 1 down die at q2?

Comment: ...because there is no arrow leaving q2 for the input `1`, so that branch dies

Comment: It starts at q1 and then gets the input 1. It can either go to q1, q2 or q3 and then get the next input. In this case going to q2, getting the next input and going to q3 is the same as going straight to q3 and getting the input after. Basically, it's not showing it because it's a duplicate of the q3 path next to it.

Comment: @Nemo No he's asking why it doesn't continue since I said you can take an empty string at *any* time. (Eugh... my brains starting to hurt from all this thinking)